# JS timer/countdown/ticker package or utility

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have found myself using the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` for different types of functions like making a countdown timer on buttons showing how many seconds left until a redirect, or running some sort of functionality every random interval between 5 and 20 seconds for a certain amount of time lets say 6 seconds.

If there any library that simplifies this at all?
I thought of some sort of api that could work in a lot of these scenarios:

```js
timer({
  timer_type: "count_down",
  timer_end: 5000,
  timer_start: 0,
  interval: 1000, // if interval is 0 then interval becomes random between 1000 and 2000 ms
  interval_rand_min: 1000, // interval is ignored if this is and interval_rand_max is used
  interval_rand_max: 1000,
  before_start_callback: first_callback,
  main_callback: main_callback,
  finish_callback: finish_callback
})
```

A countdown timer from 5 secs to 0 out putting the current count:

```
timer({
  timer_type: "count_down",
  timer_start: 5000,
  interval: 1000,
  main_callback: () => {console.log(i + "seconds left")},
  finish_callback: () => {console.log("countdown finished")}
})
```

This is a countup timer from 0 secs to 5 out putting the current count

```js
timer({
  timer_type: "count_up",
  timer_end: 5000,
  timer_start: 0,
  interval: 1000,
  main_callback: () => {console.log(i)},
  finish_callback: () => {console.log("finished")}
})
```

etc...

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EasyTimer.js](https://github.com/albert-gonzalez/easytimer.js), it seems to have almost everything you need.

A random interval is something you should really be doing yourself, it's not really the job of a library to decide how to specifically implement this.